# Curly bracket constructors?

Tags: crystal-lang

While reading through the Crystal docs, I came across this line:

```
 deq = Deque{2, 3}
```

So I think this calls the `Deque.new(array : Array(T))` constructor. However, I did not find any documentation about this syntax whatsoever. 
(**EDIT**: [The documentation can be found here](https://crystal-lang.org/docs/syntax_and_semantics/literals/array.html))

To test this way of calling constructors, I wrote the following test

```
class Foo(T)
  def initialize(@bar : Array(T)); end

  def to_s(io : IO)
    io << "Foo: "
    io << @bar
  end
end

puts Foo{1} # Line 10
```

But, compiling it prints this error:

```
Error in line 10: wrong number of arguments for 'Foo(Int32).new' (given 0, expected 1)
Overloads are:
 - Foo(T).new(bar : Array(T))
```

Which I really don't understand at all.
`Foo(Int32){1}` Raises the same error.

Question is, what is this `Klass{1, 2, 3}` syntax? And how do you use it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are documented here: https://crystal-lang.org/docs/syntax_and_semantics/literals/array.html

---

### Array-like Type Literal

Crystal supports an additional literal for arrays and array-like types. It consists of the name of the type followed by a list of elements enclosed in curly braces (`{}`) and individual elements separated by a comma (`,`).

```
Array{1, 2, 3}
```

This literal can be used with any type as long as it has an argless constructor and responds to `<<`.

```
IO::Memory{1, 2, 3}
Set{1, 2, 3}
```

For a non-generic type like `IO::Memory`, this is equivalent to:

```
array_like = IO::Memory.new
array_like << 1
array_like << 2
array_like << 3
```

For a generic type like `Set`, the generic type `T` is inferred from the types of the elements in the same way as with the array literal. The above is equivalent to:

```
array_like = Set(typeof(1, 2, 3)).new
array_like << 1
array_like << 2
array_like << 3
```

The type arguments can be explicitly specified as part of the type name:

```
Set(Number) {1, 2, 3}
```

Answer (score 3):

To create such a type you need to define an argless contructor and `#<<` method:

```
class Foo(T)
  def initialize
    @store = Array(T).new
  end

  def <<(elem : T)
    @store << elem
  end
end

foo = Foo(Int32){1, 2, 3}
p foo #=> #<Foo(Int32):0x103440b20 @store=[1, 2, 3]>
```